# How to translate column values to row values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to translate column values to rows in PostgreSQL. Every player can play **maximum of 3** matches per series (bof2). For every game he has **pokemon** he picked and points he **scored**.  Here is how it looks:

| Player | Pokemon Picked | Picked | Match Series | Match id | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ash | Charmander | 1 | 213 | 101 | 43 |
| Ash | Bulbasor | 2 | 213 | 102 | 52 |
| Ash | Pikachu | 3 | 213 | 103 | 70 |
| Brock | Onyx | 1 | 145 | 157 | 57 |
| Brock | Magmar | 2 | 145 | 158 | 63 |
| Gary | Charmander | 1 | 213 | 101 | 56 |
| Gary | Nidoking | 2 | 213 | 102 | 36 |
| Gary | Magmar | 3 | 213 | 103 | 34 |

Wanted Outcome:

| Player | First Match Pokemon | First Match Points | Second Match Pokemon | Second Match Points | Third Match Pokemon | Third Match Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ash | Charmander | 43 | Bulbasor | 52 | Pikachu | 70 |
| Brock | Onyx | 57 | Magmar | 63 | null | null |
| Gary | Charmander | 56 | Nidoking | 36 | Magmar | 34 |

I have tried using nth_element and ronumber() but cant figure it out with neither one.

Comment: An idea could be to JOIN 3 tables for the first, second, and thrid matches accordingly and then get data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on picked column value retrieve first, second and third match pokemon and points. Use Player wise group by and MAX() function because showing single row.

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT Player
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 1 THEN Pokemon_Picked END) "First Match Pokemon"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 1 THEN Points END) "First Match Points"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 2 THEN Pokemon_Picked END) "Second Match Pokemon"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 2 THEN Points END) "Second Match Points"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 3 THEN Pokemon_Picked END) "Third Match Pokemon"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Picked = 3 THEN Points END) "Third Match Points"
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Player
```

Comment: This solved my problem, didnt even think to go this rout.

Comment: @Alex thanks for upvote. If this help you then please mark it as accepted along with upvote. So anyone can pick this without any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

First off while what you want is doable in SQL, you are virtually always better off leaving the pivoting operation to your app's presentation manager.  This is because that operation always requires a priori knowledge of the number of rows (at least per group). This makes maintenance for SQL implementation a problem (query must be rewritten), while app based pivoting may require no changes.  
However there are several approaches. One is use the LEAD function to pick-off each succeeding value set, then compress the single row for each. ([see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=565e005223c57560879a7077080ca079))

```
with player_match_points ( player, pm1, pt1, pm2, pt2, pm3, pt3, rn) as   
     ( select player                       
            , pokemon                      
            , points                         
            , lead ( pokemon, 1) over (w)   
            , lead ( points,  1) over (w)  
            , lead ( pokemon, 2) over (w)   
            , lead ( points,  2) over (w)    
            , row_number (*)     over (w) 
         from matches 
        window w as (partition by player  
                         order by series, picked)
     ) 
select player   "Player"  
     , pm1      "First Match Pokemon"
     , pt1      "First Match Points"
     , pm2      "Second Match Pokemon"
     , pt2      "Second Match Points"
     , pm3      "Third Match Pokemon"
     , pt3      "Third Match Points"
  from player_match_points
 where rn=1;
```